# Change color of bootstrap scrollbar - scrollspy?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a working scrollbar using Bootstrap scrollspy but can't figure out how to change the color of the bar (thumb?).

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container, scrollbar" id="myScrollspy">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

    ...
```

CSS:

```
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #D62929;
}
```

This isn't changing the color of the bar in the scrollbar. Is there something different in the way bootstrap styles a scrollbar?

Comment: Could you please provide sample code?

Comment: Im not clear your questions anyway  Did you want to like this https://codepen.io/devstreak/pen/dMYgeO

Comment: I've edited my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change the color of scrollbar thumb this will be helpful.Be more specific with a sample code or a screenshot.

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1; 
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555; 
}
```

Comment: I've edited my code above. I'm using bootstrap to create the scrollbar. The edits you suggest aren't working.

Comment: Yo need to change the color of entire page scroll thumb or particular to that div? @sbaden

Comment: I'm trying to change the color of the entire page scroll thumb. I can't find any documentation for changing this using the bootstrap scrollspy.

Comment: you are giving style to this .scrollbar class. Give it to body